# Can't get a Public Link to test iOS app on TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I've a app and I want use the External Testers with Public Link. I can use with TestFlight in internal testers.

1. In "Builds->iOS->Testers" I added the external group target (Público em Geral).

[image]

2. In "Testers & Groups->Público em Geral", I see "No builds available" in the box of Public Link.

[image]

So, how I solve this to use public link?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you make need to add some builds to your tester group, so that the public link can be enabled.

Try the following:

1. Go to your Testers Group (i.e. "Testers & Groups->Público em Geral" in your 2nd screenshot)
2. Click on the "Builds" tab
3. Add one of the builds that you’ve uploaded recently
4. Click back to the "Testers" tab

You should now see an option for "Enable Public Link".

I found [this article](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/testflight-public-beta-invite-links-ios-beta-testing-made-simple-97d2023791d0) pretty handy for some step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get public link access unless or until you get a mail from app store connect, stating that

> Build 1.0 (1) of your app has been approved for TestFlight beta
>   testing.

Once you received a mail stating the above content **enable public link option** will be visible.

Hope this helps you.